# How to get the Windows username of the visitor from Bottle on CherryPy?

Tags: python, bottle

I am trying to see if it is possible to retrieve the Windows username of the visitor in the following config:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, request

@route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World'


run(host = '0.0.0.0', port=1986, server ='cherrypy')
```

Is it possible to get the windows username of the visitor easily without having to run this on an IIS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A HTTP request usually does not include any information about the desktop user making the request.